# .NET Core Tasks not working on OpenVZ virtual server

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, openvz, virtual-server

I noticed that .NET Core 3 `Task`s are not working on my Ubuntu 18.04 based virtual servers (the providers are Strato.de and HostEurope.de).

Here is a very basic test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(_ => Console.WriteLine("Fire"));
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("Exit");
}
```

The application should print `"Hello"`immediately, then after 2 seconds `"Fire"` and finally `"Exit"`.
This works fine on my Windows computer and also on my Ubuntu 18.04 computer.

But when I run the code on the virtual servers, the second message is never printed. Also `Threading.Timer` and `Timers.Timer` have the same problem, they almost never fire (sometimes, but very rarely, they do).

EDIT: Both virtual servers run on **OpenVZ**, at least this is what `systemd-detect-virt` says. I changed the title of the question accordingly.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: If it's wrong, please show me a corrected example. I can not see why async should fix it.

Comment: I already checked if there are not enough threads available on the virtual server (using the methods of `ThreadPool`), but this seems not to be the problem:
````Min threads: 6 * worker, 6 * completion; Max threads: 32767 * worker, 1000 * completion; Available threads: 32767 * worker, 1000 * completion````

Comment: The problem does *not appear on* a Ubuntu 18.04 server hosted by *Azure* (underlying virtualization is "Microsoft ..." and not "OpenVM").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and is going to be fixed in .NET Core 3.1.2

See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2070 and https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/26873

Answer (score 1):

If able to use an asynchronous `Main`, then consider the following

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    var task1 = Task.Run(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Fire");
    });
    var task2 = Task.Delay(5000);
    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
    Console.WriteLine("Exit");
}
```

Avoid mixing asynchronous and blocking calls like `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` respectively. If going async, go all the way.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is _not_ the solution to my problem. Running your code on both virtual servers, only "Hello" is printed, then the program "freezes", because the tasks seem never to run.